# No playable missions after, mr Philips GTA V

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've played the mission mr Philips but then I can't play any more, I did not receive a call from Ron, nor can I play as Michael or Franklin due to the jewel store job, please help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem just call Ron and the next mission will pop up on the map

Answer (score -2):

So I found out I started the game over but I noticed I had a mission with Lamar that I never did somehow this got pass the game so it doesn’t know you can’t access them so unless you have a save b4 that just start over your not that far